# How would one characterize intensity of diffuse scattering as a function of roughness

Tags: optics

How would one even characterize roughness of a material experimentally using statistical analysis or by a set of equations 
And how would I relate the roughness to the intensity of light scattering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second part:  it's almost always done empirically by measuring a sample of the surface.  The standard equation is known as the [bidirectional reflectance distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_reflectance_distribution_function), which one uses to estimate the scattered power into a given angle based on the incoming angle of the light.

Surface roughness and its parametrization is a science unto itself.  The behavior of the surface depends on the material type and on the "shape" of the roughness.  For a couple examples, a perfectly regular set of grooves is known as a diffraction grating, while a randomized-polished surface is described by "Scratch and Dig," denoting length and depth parameters of the irregularities.  But there are other surfaces, such as "gold black," where gold is deliberately deposited as microscopic spheres of random location and size so as to produce a surface with almost zero reflectivity.